# Angular show on click

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click, angularjs-ng-show

```
<button ng-show="color.show" ng-click="addNewColor(color);color.show=false;">Add this color to mine collection</button>
```

I have this code and when i click on that button, button does not disappear. When I go somewhere else and come back into that template(i am using angularUI router) that button disappears. color.show define variable is true.

Comment: why don't you move color.show statement into addNewColor function

Comment: I agree with @TechMa9iac, try to avoid this style of `ng-click` directive. You can't debug this part of code

Comment: Like this : `function addNewColor(color){   
   $scope.color.show = false;
};`

Comment: apart from moving code to function... your code should work as is, dont see any issue with the code as such

Comment: @TechMa9iac i moved color.show into addNewColor and it works

Comment: Glad it helped @GoncharDenys.. (y) !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have a **js error** in this expression:

```
addNewColor(color);
```

Look at this fiddle [example](http://jsfiddle.net/ppsgfhjj/) and see that everything works correctly if there are no **js errors**.

Comment: Well, i made few changes to look mine code more like in your example and it works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have made a sample program for your code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/QYuRTRKuRU3wqfHPdIew?p=preview).

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="myController">
  <button ng-show="color.show" ng-click="addColor(color);color.show=false;">Add this color to mine collection</button>
</div>
</body>
```

As it is, this code is working, you might have written some code in addColor() that might be breaking your code.